# FFMPEG - local video to UDP streaming to OpenCV - video quality degraded

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

my goal is to re-stream local video content / desktop screencasting, to an UDP flow that I need to process on a Python script.

Here is the FFMPEG script that I'm using:

```
ffmpeg -re -i C:\Users\test\Downloads\out.ts -strict -2 -c:v copy -an -preset slower -tune stillimage -b 11200k -f rawvideo udp://127.0.0.1:5000
```

And here is the simple Python script supposed to read the stream flow:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('udp://127.0.0.1:5000',cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)
if not cap.isOpened():
    print('VideoCapture not opened')
    exit(-1)
width = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)  # float
height = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)  # float
print(str(width))
print(str(height))
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    imgray = frame[int(round((height/100)*70,0)):int(round((width/100)*42,0)), int(round((height/100)*74,0)):int(round((width/100)*54,0))]
    if not ret:
        print('frame empty')
        break
    cv2.imshow('image', imgray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1)&0XFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
```

I'm able to visualize portion of the stream video as expect, but I'm facing lot of issue in video quality degradation, specially video artifact probably due missing packet processing:

[image]

Also these are error log I'm geting from script:

```
[h264 @ 0000026eb272f280] error while decoding MB 105 66, bytestream -21
[h264 @ 0000026eb2fcb740] error while decoding MB 100 53, bytestream -11
[h264 @ 0000026eb272f280] error while decoding MB 32 22, bytestream -11
[h264 @ 0000026ead9ee300] error while decoding MB 60 20, bytestream -25
[h264 @ 0000026eb27f00c0] error while decoding MB 9 62, bytestream -5
[h264 @ 0000026ead9ee780] error while decoding MB 85 44, bytestream -5
[h264 @ 0000026eb27f0800] error while decoding MB 64 25, bytestream -15
[h264 @ 0000026eb272f280] error while decoding MB 112 23, bytestream -17
[h264 @ 0000026eb2735200] error while decoding MB 30 21, bytestream -7
```

Actually I don't care about video fluidity,I can also reduce the FPS, important thing is the video quality. Not sure if I'm doing wrong on the scripting python part or if I'm using wrong FFMPEG command.

Many Thanks

Comment: Did you finally get a solution to this? I overcame the problem after I raised the buffersize from default to 65535 (after the udp port address in the cv2.VideoCapture) and it worked for me.

Comment: No I did not found a solution yet. How did you modify the Buffer size? cv2.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, 65535)?

Answer (score 2):

For video quality you will have to use multi-threading. It'll fix it up. I will give you an example that you can work on.

```py
import threading
import queue
import cv2

q = queue.Queue()

def receive():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('udp://@127.0.0.1:5000?buffer_size=65535&pkt_size=65535&fifo_size=65535')
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    q.put(frame)
    while ret:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        q.put(frame)

def display():
    while True:
        if q.empty() != True:
            frame = q.get()
            cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

        k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff
        if k == 27:  # press 'ESC' to quit
            break

tr = threading.Thread(target=receive, daemon=True)
td = threading.Thread(target=display)

tr.start()
td.start()

td.join()
```